# ajax receives response from php but can not use with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following php and ajax code when I check in google chrome with `ctrl+shift+I` in network tab it shows the response as `<{"response" : "2"}` but this response can't be assigned to `<h3>` having id as respo

**my php is**

```
<<?php

$id = $_POST['reccount'];
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testsite");
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// Attempt update query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM paper WHERE ID=$id";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data['response']= $row['response'];
    $data['ansnum'] = $row['q_no'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

**and ajax is**

```
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo base_url();?>/shortfiles/loadans.php",
        data: {reccount: reccount},
         dataType:"JSON",
          success: function(data){
          alert (data.response);
           $('#respond').text(data.response);
                          }


                    })  ;
```

and html is

```
<h3 ID="respond"style="margin-left:30px;">response</h3>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your PHP, where is `$data` defined *before* the while loop?

Comment: Also your MySQL Query is susceptible to SQL Injection.

Comment: html attributes should be lower case

Comment: I think the issue is the `<<?php` you have. This is resulting in incorrect JSON format. If the response is: `<{"response": 2}` this would cause an issue in parsing the JSON in jQuery. Suggest you change it to `<?php` for correct formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If the response from your PHP is:

```
<{"response" : "2"}
```

This would be an incorrectly formatted JSON string. This would be created by the extra `<` you have at the beginning of the document. I would advise you have the following PHP Opener:

```
<?php
```

This should correct the issue so the JSON Response would be:

```
{"response" : "2"}
```

It will be properly parse at that point.

**Example**

```
<?php
$id = (int)$_POST['reccount'];
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testsite");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if($link === false){
  die("{\"error\": \"Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error() . "\"}");
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM paper WHERE ID=$id";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data['response']= $row['response'];
    $data['ansnum'] = $row['q_no'];
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
} else {
  echo "{\"error\": \"Unable to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link) . "\"}";
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

In my example, I cast the POST data to Integer to help ensure a malicious user does not get to send anything other than a digit. I also only send JSON data, even when sending an error. Using the `header()` helps define the data for the browser.

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"<?php echo base_url();?>/shortfiles/loadans.php",
  data: {reccount: reccount},
  dataType:"JSON",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    if(data.error !== undefined){
      alert(data.error);
    } else {
      $('#respond').text(data.response);
    }
  }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @manoj great. If this post helped or answered your question, please upvote it and mark it as the answer.